Query parameter Validation in Rocket
I lost and unable to figure out a clean way to validate query parameters in my GET request. I want to return an error message that a parameter is missing or invalid using rocket::form::FromForm or any other way but cannot make progress.
I am using:
rocket_okapi = "0.8.0"
rocket = { version = "0.5.0", features = ["json"] }

// CONTEXT
#[derive(Serialize, JsonSchema, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Error {
    pub err: String,
    pub msg: Option<String>,
    #[serde(skip)]
    pub http_status_code: Status,
}
// JsonError exists for the sole purpose of adding traits
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct JsonError(Json<Error>);

pub type Result<T> = std::result::Result<json::Json<T>, crate::JsonError>;

#[derive(JsonSchema, Serialize, FromForm)]
pub struct HistoryRequest {
    pub start_date: String,
    pub end_date: String,
}

// PROBLEM
#[openapi]
#[get("/history?<query..>")]
async fn history(
    query: HistoryRequest,
    user_account_id: AuthGuard,
    db_pool: DbConn,
) -> crate::Result<HistoryRequest> {
    Ok(Json(query))
}

Problems:

The route is skipped if not all parameters are provided.
I cannot validate the request without using FromRequest
I cannot use Form<HistoryRequest> because JsonSchema is not implemented for rocket::form::Form<HistoryRequest> and I need it for OpenApi. Similarily using std::Result<HistoryRequest, rocket::form::Error> JsonSchema is not implemented.
I cannot use std::Result<HistoryRequest, JsonError> because a lot of issues pop up. One of which is if I add FromForm to my Error struct then it complains that Status does not implement FromFormField.

I could make the struct parameters as Option<String> and then implement the FromRequest trait but this seems impractical to do for each GET request that I want to validate. Is there really no better way to do this? In rocket v0.4 I saw that there was FromQuery but apparently it got merged into FromForm. Now I am lost on how am I supposed to do this.
There seems plenty of documentation on POST using FromForm but not much on GET requests.
It would be great if it was possible to use FromForm with #[field(validate = ...)]
If you have any ideas or suggestions please help.
